# Tabla de frecuencia con valores específicos

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Quiero realizar una tabla de frecuencias de mi data frame, de tal manera, que en los datos de género (escrita como RIAGENDR) solo seleccione a las mujeres (designadas como 2, hombres como 1) y cuente el número de observaciones en una variable designada como DMDMARTL (estado civil: 1 ==> casada, 2 ==> viuda, 3 ==> divorciada, 4 ==> separada, 5 ==> nunca se casó, 6 == > viviendo con pareja).

Mi da.head() es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El data frame está disponible en:https://www.kaggle.com/ramendrapandey/nhanes-2015-2016

Mi código para seleccionar las variables de mi data frame (RIAGENDR y DMDMARTL) y hacer el conteo de frecuencias (en el caso de RIAGENDR (género) solo seleccionar a las mujeres (2)) es el siguiente:

```
pd.crosstab(index = da["RIAGENDR"] == 2, columns = da["DMDMARTL"])
```

Con ese código me muestra lo siguiente:

| DMDMARTL | 1.0 | 2.0 | 3.0 | 4.0 | 5.0 | 6.0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RIAGENDR |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| False | 1477 | 100 | 229 | 68 | 484 | 265 |
| True | 1303 | 296 | 350 | 118 | 520 | 262 |

Intuyo que True es el valor 2 (mujer) y el False corresponde a 1(hombre). Sin embargo, deseo que en vez de esos valores booleanos me muestre el número 2 y sus respectivos valores en cada categoria de la variable DMDMARTL(estado civil). ¿Cómo podría modificar mi código para que haga lo mencionado?

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar parte del dataframe de entrada `da` para ver qué valores toman las filas y columnas y así entender de dónde salen esos False y True?

Comment: Edité la publicación. También dejé el link del dataframe. Se puede ver en Kaggle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que buscas es solo para el caso de las mujeres, eso se puede obtener de forma más simple. Basta seleccionar (usando `.loc[]`) todas las filas en las que "RIAGENDR" valga 2, y la columna "DMDMARTL", para aplicarle a esa selección la operación `.value_counts()`

Así:

```py
da.loc[da["RIAGENDR"]==2, "DMDMARTL"].value_counts().sort_index()
```

y eso produce el resultado:

|  | DMDMARTL |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1303 |
| 2 | 296 |
| 3 | 350 |
| 4 | 118 |
| 5 | 520 |
| 6 | 262 |
| 77 | 1 |

(por cierto que en el dataframe que he bajado de Kaggle parece haber un caso en el que DMDMARTL toma el valor 77)

### Usando crosstab

Si prefieres hacerlo con `crosstab`, porque quieres obtener los contadores tantopara hombres como para mujeres, lo que te ocurría es que estás usando como índice del resultado un booleano que es `True` cuando RIAGENDR es 2 y `False` cuando es distinto de 2, debido a que haces `da["RIAGENDR"]==2` y esa comparación sale `True` o `False` elemento a elemento.

Para obtener en cambio directamente 1 y 2, basta que no hagas ninguna comparación, sino que uses como índice los valores de la columna "RIAGENDR":

```
pd.crosstab(index = da["RIAGENDR"], columns = da["DMDMARTL"])
```

Y el resultado es ahora:

| DMDMARTL | 1.0 | 2.0 | 3.0 | 4.0 | 5.0 | 6.0 | 77.0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RIAGENDR |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | 1477 | 100 | 229 | 68 | 484 | 265 | 1 |
| 2 | 1303 | 296 | 350 | 118 | 520 | 262 | 1 |

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda! En efecto, con .loc[] es la mejor solución a lo que buscaba. Solo me surge una duda. Puedes seleccionar múltiples variables o es mejor usar groupby. Por ejemplo, si seleccionas la variable RIDAGEYR (variable de edades) y defines un intervalo para saber el número de frecuencia que se encuentra en DMDMARTL: `da.loc[((da["RIDAGEYR"] >= 30) & (da["RIDAGEYR"] <= 40), "DMDMARTL")].value_counts().sort_index()`  ¿también se podría agregar un género específico? Es decir, el cuantas mujeres u hombres se observan en el intervalo definido en cada una de las categorías DMDMART

Comment: No veo nada malo en poner varias condiciones para seleccionar rangos de edades (aunque creo que has puesto unos paréntesis de más alrededor de todo lo que va en el .loc[]). Pero para lo segundo que preguntas ¿no es esa precisamente la salida obtenida con crosstab? ¿O te refieres a combinar condiciones de rangos de edades **y** condiciones de un género concreto? Sí, eso también podría hacerse a base de `&`.

Comment: Me refiero a combinar condiciones de rangos de edades y condiciones de género (por ejemplo, solo mujeres). Tipo:  `da.loc[((da["RIDAGEYR"] >= 30) & (da["RIDAGEYR"] <= 40), "DMDMARTL", ["RIAGENDR"] ==2)].value_counts().sort_index()` . Aunque esta mal la sintaxis. Por otra parte, el código: `da.loc[((da["RIDAGEYR"] >= 30) & (da["RIDAGEYR"] <= 40), "DMDMARTL")].value_counts().sort_index()`. sí me corre.  Selecciona a las personas entre 30 y 40, tanto a hombres como mujeres y su estado civil. Al momento de querer indicar un género específico es cuando me dice "Too many indexers".

Comment: Porque todas las condiciones que quieras aplicar van en la primera parte, antes de la coma. Sería así: `da.loc[(da["RIDAGEYR"] >= 30) & (da["RIDAGEYR"] <= 40 & (da["RIAGENDR"]==2), "DMDMARTL"].value_counts().sort_index()`. La primera parte, hasta la coma, selecciona qué filas de `da` se usarán (las que cumplan la expresión booleana). La segunda parte, después de la coma, selecciona con qué columnas te quedarás para aplicar `.value_counts()`.